# AngularJS's deferred promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a working $http.POST request in a factory whose job is to get a list object and return it. Simple as that, except the object property I'm returning it to just grows legs and leaves. I'll explain:

just the problem bit for right now, everything else seems to be working fine though

```
$scope.updateObj = function(num) {
    console.log("Obj before:\n" + JSON.stringify($scope.Obj));
    $scope.Obj.name = "Obj_" + num;
    $scope.Obj.list = myFactory.getList($scope.Obj.name);
    window.setTimeout(console.log("Obj after:\n" + JSON.stringify($scope.Obj)), 3000);
};
```

The console.log before the update displays the object just as defined in myController.js, and the console.log after the update has the correct updated information, but is missing the list property altogether.

I set the the console.log checking Obj after the update on a timeout to see if the request just needed a little more time, but I don't think it's working as intended. I'm thinking it's an asynchronous problem, but I'm still fairly new, and I don't have a good grasp on how to use the $q service.

**tld;dr: How do I asynchronously attach response.data from $http to an object property?**

---

**myFactory.js**

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getList = function(name) {
        try {
            console.log("getting" + name);
            var temp = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'yourmom.com',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: {list: name},
                cache: true
            }).then(
                function success(response) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.list)); // <- checks out & is exactly what I expect.
                    return response.data.list;
                },
                function error(response) {
                    throw error(response.status);
                }
            );
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert(err);
            return undefined;
        }
    };

    return service;
});
```

**myController.js**

```
app.controller('GUIcontroller', ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'networkFactory', function($scope, myFactory, networkFactory) {
    $scope.number = undefined;

    $scope.networkInit = networkFactory.init();
    $scope.Obj = {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        list: {}
    };

    $scope.updateObj = function(num) {
        console.log("Obj before:\n" + JSON.stringify($scope.Obj));
        $scope.Obj.name = "Obj_" + num;
        $scope.Obj.list = myFactory.getList($scope.Obj.name);
        console.log("Obj after:\n" + JSON.stringify($scope.Obj));
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You must pass a callback to `setTimeout`, instead of calling `console.log()` immediately and passing its result

Comment: Your `getList` function should return the promise (and you can omit the try-catch), and you should await that promises result instead of using an arbitrary timeout

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about promises differently. The main benefit of having promises is that you get the result exactly when it's done, whether it's successful or throws an error.

This is a proposed way of doing what you're trying to achieve:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getList = function(name) {
        return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'yourmom.com',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: {list: name},
                cache: true
            });
    };

    return service;
});

app.controller('GUIcontroller', ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'networkFactory', function($scope, myFactory, networkFactory) {
    $scope.number = undefined;

    $scope.networkInit = networkFactory.init();
    $scope.Obj = {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        list: {}
    };

    $scope.updateObj = function(num) {
        $scope.Obj.name = "Obj_" + num;
        myFactory.getList($scope.Obj.name).then(function(response) {
            $scope.Obj.list = response;
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error('Error fetching list: ', err);
        });
    };
}]);
```